# Send-MailMessage parameter from command prompt

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run `Send-MailMessage` directly from a command window.

`C:\>powershell Send-MailMessage -from 'test@test.com' -to "target@test.com" -subject 'test' -smtpServer "srv.server.com" -Attachment c:\Test\log.txt -body "Test message"`

This fails with

`Send-MailMessage : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'from'.`

I'm sure it's possible. I just dont know how to pass the arguments correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running this from cmd.exe then you need to check out the PowerShell.exe help:

```
C:\> poweshell.exe /?
```

Specifically you should invoke the command like so:

```
C:\> powershell -command "& {Send-MailMessage -from 'test@test.com' ... }"
```

Watch out for the quote characters.  In general use double quotes around the whole -command parameter value for cmd.exe interpret.  Inside the command use single quoted strings unless you need variable expansion inside the string.

Comment: do you know how to make the command multiline ? to be executed from bat ?